# Starting a different app from within another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 applications: App A and App B. In App A, I can click on something which will launch an intent and open up App B. This intent will bring the user to an activity that IS NOT the main activity of App B, let's call it ViewFormsActivity. This is the code for the on click in App A

```
Intent intent = new Intent("forms.ViewFormsActivity");
                intent.putExtra("formID", formID);
                intent.putExtra("siteID", siteID);
                intent.putExtra("tab", 0);
                intent.putExtra("prePopulatedURL", modifiedURL);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is the manifest for App B

```
<activity
        android:name=".ViewFormsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_forms"
        android:exported="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="forms.ViewFormsActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This code works when App B has not been opened yet. However, if I leave App B on the main activity, and switch to App A, and perform the click; the user is taken to the main activity page of App B. It does not seem to bring the user to the ViewFormsActivity, even though I specified that in the intent. Anyone know the reason why, and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Add `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)` as a flag and add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the receiving activities manifest.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to open an activity from another app, you'll have to include the ComponentName too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponentName(new ComponentName(PACKAGE_NAME, com.something.something.forms.ViewFormsActivity.class));
intent.putExtra("formID", formID);
intent.putExtra("siteID", siteID);
intent.putExtra("tab", 0);
intent.putExtra("prePopulatedURL", modifiedURL);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding flag_activity_clear_top to the intent from App A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("forms.ViewFormsActivity");
                intent.putExtra("formID", formID);
                intent.putExtra("siteID", siteID);
                intent.putExtra("tab", 0);
                intent.putExtra("prePopulatedURL", modifiedURL);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```